# PDFBox - show icon for embedded files in pdf

Tags: java, icons, rendering, pdfbox, attachment

I developed a Java PDF viewer using Apache PDFBox. The problem is, when rendering a page of a PDF, if the page has file attachments, there is no icon shown in PDFBox rendering, like there is a paper clip icon, when such a file is opened in Adobe PDF reader.
Is it possible to automatically have such icons in the rendering using PDFBox? I think I saw such a code some time ago, like a single line that switches this behavior on and off but I can't find it. Thanks.

Comment: Ideally the appearance should be in the PDF itself, but obviously yours isn't. I implemented many annotation appearance handlers in 2018. IIRC I didn't implement a handler for that type because I didn't find a paperclip symbol in the Zapf Dingbats font  (which is assumed to exist on each machine). Please share your PDF. If anybody has a paperclip symbol that is apache licensed, or in a font that is Apache or SIL licensed, please create a ticket in PDFBox JIRA.

Comment: @KJ thanks. That seems interesting. I right clicked on my sample PDF with attachment on the paper clip symbol, there a dialog opens where one can change it to like paper pin, graph and all attachment name strings defined in your link. But idk how to render it automatically. I think there's a one-liner that does it but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have not created the sample PDF, it was a feature request. I can't share it bc it's intern but I try to get the sample LaTeX code and share one here. When I open same doc in Adobe Reader it shows a symbol but not using PDFBox render method. Thats funny with the font  I search a Apache license icon. Is MIT license also ok? If that gets implemented then, PDFBox will render it?

Comment: Yes MIT is fine. https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html  I found an apache licensed paperclip vector graphic https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Iconscout/unicons/master/svg/line/paperclip.svg but it is diagonal. (I know I can rotate it but that's extra work).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes, this looks visually like the same rotated paper clip icon I found. Rotated is just fine. Should I open a PDFBox JIRA issue?

Comment: Yes please do, but don't expect it to be fixed very fast. In the meantime I found a PDF, http://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_commenting_new.pdf , page 8. There are (at least) 4 symbols. (Graph, PushPin, Paperclip, Tag).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you, I'll do that. I tried this PDF and Adobe Reader shows the symbols (little paper blocks for me) but not rendered in PDFBox.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in [PDFBOX-5394](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5394) and will be in the version 2.0.26. However only one single symbol will be shown at this time: a paperclip in fixed size.